# Shortening conditional in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am wondering what is the most succinct way of writing the following conditional?

```
if not 0.01 < parameters[0] <1. or not 0.01 < parameters[1] <2. or not 0.01 < parameters[2] <0.25 or not 0.01 < parameters[3] <0.25 or not 0.01 < parameters[4] < 0.2
    #do something
```

Comment: It there a kind of logic in the right values of the comparisons?

Comment: Perhaps you are asking the wrong question.  Do you want the most _succinct_ code, or do you want the most _clear_ code?

Comment: No logic, they're based on physiological measurements, but there is no clear correlation.

Comment: And good question! I think I want the clearest code, but I am also curious as to how can this be made most succinct in Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a clear code I'd say:

```
parameters = [0,0,0,0,0]

LBS = [.01, .01, .01, .01, .01]
UBS = [1., 2., .25, .25, .2]

conds = (not (LB < param < UB) for param, LB, UB in zip(parameters, LBS, UBS))

if all(conds):
    # Action
```

Or more effective:

```
conds = (LB < param < UB for param, LB, UB in zip(parameters, LBS, UBS))

if not any(conds):
    # Action
```

Or:

```
if not any(LB < param < UB for param, LB, UB in zip(parameters, LBS, UBS)):
```

---

**Explanation:**

Let us put all your conditions in a list/generator by zipping together your params, lower bounds (LBS) and upper bounds (UBS).

We then check if all conds are True with `all(conds)` and execute if `True`.

Comment: You only need one of the conditions to be true to enter the `if`. In this case you need `any(conds)`, not `all(conds)`.

Comment: @tmoisan You are right. I have added a more effective solution using any.

Comment: Potentially silly question but when I run this `parameters=[0.,0.2]
lbs = [.01, .01]
ups = [1., 2.]

conds = (not (lb < param < up) for param, lb, up in zip(parameters, lbs, ups))
print(conds)

if any(conds):
    print('test')

if any(conds):
 print('test1')` This will only print the first test, I am bit confused as to why that is? I haven't used generators before so I might be misunderstanding something here.

Comment: @Ale A generator is consumed when iterated over.

Comment: That's so curious! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Ale Yes indeed. And a lot of things in Python are returned as iterators. For instance zip(x,y) returns an iterator. If you replace the outer `()` with `[]` your code becomes runnable. In this case we store it as a list instead of generator.

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to simplify multiple `or` is to use the python [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) built-in. In this case, you would get something like this:

```
upper_bounds = [1, 2, 0.25, 0.25, 0.2]
if any([not 0.01 < parameters[i] < up for i, up in enumerate(upper_bounds)]):
    # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `clear` solution, I'd go with what Anton wrote above me. But, the question asked for the most `succinct`. This is what I came up with.

```
if len(list(filter(lambda p: p[1] <= 0.01 or p[1] >= [1,2,.25,.25,.2][p[0]],enumerate(parameters)))) != 0:
    print('Do something')
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be clearer, or at least easier to see what you want the values to be between:

```
floor= 0.01
array = [1,2,0.25,0.25,0.2,0.01]
if not floor < parameters[0] <array[0] 
or 
not floor < parameters[1] <array[1] 
or 
not floor < parameters[2] <array[2] 
or 
not floor < parameters[3] <array[3] 
or 
not floor < parameters[4] < array[4]
```